# How can I install odia language in my sony Xperia mdual mobile phone

Tags: 4.3-jelly-bean, languages

Kindly give me suggestion,How can I install odia language in my sony Xperia mdual mobile phone.

Answer (score 1):

Odia fonts are supported only in Android 5.1.1 and later. However you can read Odia fonts in a web browser by following these steps:

1. Install Firefox browser from Google Play Store.
2. Launch Firefox and go to the Oriya fonts package Add-Ons page and select *Add to Firefox*.
3. Click *Install*.

To add read/write support for Odia language globally in earlier Android versions than 5.1.1, install Odia keyboard app. From [Odia keyboard](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=globe.sanshri.odiaKeyboard) app's Google Play Store webpage:

> #### Features
>
> Type in Odia or Oriyai and other Indian languages using normal keyboard
>
> - Content can be formatted with different styles, colors, sizes and shades.
> - Share as image or text with popular apps
> - SMS or message the text
> - Copy the text and paste anywhere
> - Save as text or image
> - Open or edit the saved work

Odia keyboard app requires Android 2.1 and up.

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>